# connecting to oracle in php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

i did these steps but again i couldn't connect to oracle.

1.i installed xampp

2.i installed instant client:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

3.i copied instant client to C:\ and added C:\instantclient_11_2 to path variable

4.remove comment from 
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll  ; Use with Oracle 11gR2 Instant Client

5.restart apache

note: oracle services are running and i can connect to database with sql developer

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_pconnect() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\web\dalc\db.php on line 27

```
 private function connect($url, $username, $password){
  if($this->_persistentConnections){
    $this->_cn = oci_pconnect($username, $password, $url, 'AL32UTF8');
  }else{
    $this->_cn = oci_connect($username, $password, $url, 'AL32UTF8');
  }

  $this->execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'");

  return $this->_cn;
 }
```

i can't understand what is wrong?

Comment: You are using Oracle 12c so I think you need  `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` in your `php.ini` Either that or install the 11g Oracle client

Comment: i am using oracle 11g

Comment: But the link you quote is to a 12c client

Comment: you mean C:\instantclient_12_1?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. What version of PHP are you using

Comment: can you write link that what should i install?i installed also Version 11.2.0.4.0 but it doesn't work

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94486/discussion-between-serkhan-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: I do not know a specific answer to your issue. But I do know that the versions of the Oracle client software and the PHP extension should match